# URL Query parameters are being lost

Tags: url, layered-navigation, filter, query, listing

I am having a strange issue with my product filter (layered navigation) not working, I have narrowed this down to the URL paramaters being lost because of a 301 redirect.

If I go to the URL... http://domain.local/styles/?attribute_style=258

I would expect to land on a category page with a result filtered by attribute style. This does't happen, the products aren't being filtered. This seems to be because the above URL goes to a 301 redirect and forwards me to the URL... http://domain.local/styles/ without the query string.
[image: 301 Redirect]
I am pretty sure this is related to a configuration setting as I'm sure it was fine before I imported a pre-existing database.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this and how I can resolve it?

Comment: can you check your `.htaccess` file? I guess the reason can be found there. Maybe a rewrite that expects a "/" at the end of the URL, and removes the query params? Replace the `.htaccess` by the Magento default file to test this.

Comment: I have replaced the .htaccess with the .htaccess.sample that comes with Magento but it is still doing the 301 redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to be a combination between having the trailing slash enabled and a core Magento bug.

Answer (score 1):

Besides clearing your rewriter table I guess you should clear your browser cache.

Comment: Yes browser cache is a good idea. Or have Dev-Tools open and check "Disable cache" in the network tab. Or simply do `http://domain.local/styles/?attribute_style=258` for a request that won't be cached at all.